# Application sees zero/different tables from what local DynamoDB instance has

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm building a WebAPI project. I have DynamoDB downloaded and running locally with `-inMemory`. After creating a couple of tables, I run this command locally: `aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000`, which results in:

```
{
    "TableNames": [
        "Users",
        "Tmp"
    ]
}
```

When I run my application, I create a client, and query for tables:

```cs
using (var client = DatabaseClientFactory.CreateClient())
            {
                // debugging
                var temp = await client.ListTablesAsync();
                return $"{temp.TableNames.Count} tables: " + string.Join(", ", temp.TableNames);
            }
```

This returns `0 tables:`

The DB client is a lightly-modified version of [this starter code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NET.01.html):

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;

namespace Database
{
    // Adapted from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NET.01.html
    public static class DatabaseClientFactory
    {
        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        *  If you are creating a client for the Amazon DynamoDB service, make sure your credentials
        *  are set up first, as explained in:
        *  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SettingUp.DynamoWebService.html,
        *
        *  If you are creating a client for DynamoDBLocal (for testing purposes),
        *  DynamoDB-Local should be started first. For most simple testing, you can keep
        *  data in memory only, without writing anything to disk.  To do this, use the
        *  following command line:
        *
        *    java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -inMemory
        *
        *  For information about DynamoDBLocal, see:
        *  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html.
        *-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        private const int Port = 8000;

        public static AmazonDynamoDBClient CreateClient()
        {
            // If this line throws, you need to download the AWS CLI, run `aws configure` and specify your access key.
            var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
            var dynamoDbConfig = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig();

            // First, check to see whether anyone is listening on the DynamoDB local port
            // (by default, this is port 8000, so if you are using a different port, modify this accordingly)
            var portAvailable = IsPortAvailable();

            if (portAvailable)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  -- The local instance of DynamoDB is NOT running. Using PROD.");
                // TODO: this should come out of appSettings.Production.json
                dynamoDbConfig.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast2;
            }
            else
            {
                // Local address ignores AWS credentials
                Console.WriteLine("  -- The local instance of DynamoDB is running!");
                dynamoDbConfig.ServiceURL = $"http://localhost:{Port}";
            }

            client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(dynamoDbConfig);

            return client;
        }

        private static bool IsPortAvailable()
        {
            // Evaluate current system TCP connections. This is the same information provided
            // by the netstat command line application, just in .Net strongly-typed object
            // form.  We will look through the list, and if our port we would like to use
            // in our TcpClient is occupied, we will set isAvailable to false.
            IPGlobalProperties ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
            IPEndPoint[] tcpConnInfoArray = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpListeners();

            foreach (IPEndPoint endpoint in tcpConnInfoArray)
            {
                if (endpoint.Port == Port)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

That's odd - my two tables don't appear.

Even more strange: if I make calls like `client.CreateTableAsync`, they successfully create a table, and the return value of my API call becomes `1 tables: CREATED_IN_CODE`

It seems like I have two versions of DynamoDB running locally on the same port - one the application accesses, and one that the CLI accesses.

Why is my app seeing a wrong/different list of tables?

Some other things I tried to no avail:

- Nuking/reinstalling DynamoDB
- Restarting my PC
- Reverting to a previous version of my code from earlier today
- Looking for the `CREATED_IN_CODE` table in AWS in different regions

Comment: I ran your code and it works for me.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth what's different about your environment that it works for you, but not for me?

Comment: Not sure. You might make sure you have a region set, even though it doesn't really matter. Sometimes that fixes issues like this.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth Looks like you're correct. Adding the region to app.settings and app.development.settings didn't seem to help, but hard-coding it in my client helped. Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code worked fine for me. Sometimes you need to be sure there is a region set, even though you are setting a `ServiceUrl`.

Comment: I am still not sure how this used to work - it doesn't get picked up from `AppSettings.*.json` for some reason. Hard-coding it solved my problem, thank you so much!